# JAVA: to have a toolbar to read a file from your computer

Tags: java, file, select, user-interface

I have this program that reads a video file from my computer and analysis will be done on it. 
Right now I can only read the file by changing the directory and the file name in the code.

I want to include a function to select the video file from my computer on my program's UI, like a toolbar that has browse button to select the correct directory and file that I want and my program will use it, all done on the UI.

Any tips and suggestions implementing this capability?

Comment: I haven't tried anything.. because I have limited knowledge about implementing User Interface. I need a good head start on how to implement the above capability. Any good tutorials websites to recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has [excellent documentation on the JFileChooser swing component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) that you should have a look at. Example projects are also provided there. The documentation provided is excellent. They provide a basic example of this usage that reads as follows:

```
//Create a file chooser
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
//In response to a button click:
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { // Success
    // Get filename that was picked
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    //This is where a real application would open the file.
    log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
} else { // Cancelled
    log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
}
```

Which is enough to display a file picker dialog. Beyond that you should look into making this call from and actionPerformed event, fired either by a JButton or JMenuItem, both of which also have solid documentation provided by Oracle.

I'd also recommend looking into using the [Netbeans Swing GUI](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html#project) builder if you are just starting out with Swing, particularly as layouts can become quite complicated to work with at times.

Comment: Thank you, I am reading up in the sites that you provided. (: